# multiple lists with the same callback function lead to IndexError

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for GUI and I create two lists:

```
# widgets     
create_list(win, 20, 20, ["Test", "Apfel", "Birne"])     
create_list(win, 220, 20, ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"])
```

where create_list is a function:

```
def create_list(win, xx, yy, items=\[\]):
    lb = Listbox(win)
    i = 1
    for item in items:
        lb.insert(i, item)
        i += 1    
    lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
    lb.place(x=xx, y=yy)
```

Nothing special so far.
I have one *on_select* function as callback for selection changes for both lists.

```
def on_select(event):         
    w = event.widget         
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])         
    value = w.get(index)         
    print(f'You selected item {index}: {value}')`
```

it works as expected, prints me the selected item.
However if I click an item from the second list (and wise versa) I get the error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File
> "/home/userx/projects/python/modules/ws_list.py", line 8, in on_select
> index = int(w.curselection()[0]) IndexError: tuple index out of range

If I then select another item in the same list, the issue is gone.
How am I solving that? Do I need a different callback function for each list?

Comment: You always want to use the `exportselection=False` option with the Tkinter Listbox, especially when there's more than one on screen at the same time.  The default ties the list selection to the system clipboard, so it's impossible to have selections in more than one list at the same time (and you're constantly trashing anything the user might have placed on the clipboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48676496/7519434), the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event will be fired if selection is removed from a listbox, which is what happens when you switch between lists. This will then result in an empty `curselection` which is what causes your error. To avoid this, check if the selection is empty before using it.

```
def on_select(event):         
    w = event.widget
    selection = w.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = int(selection[0])         
        value = w.get(index)         
        print(f'You selected item {index}: {value}')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change from listbox1 to listbox2, the on_select is triggered on both.
So either you account for the posibility that `w.curselection()` is empty, and hence:

```
def on_select(event):         
    w = event.widget   
    if w.curselection():
       index = int(w.curselection()[0])         
       value = w.get(index)         
       print(f'You selected item {index}: {value} in listbox: {w}')
```

or use `exportselection=False` when creating the LB to allow selecting from them individually.

You can also give listboxes a name (`name=xxx`) and you'll be able to differentiate which listbox the on_select is called from.